# Too many arguments error in shell script

Tags: shell

I am trying a simple shell script like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
up_cap=$( cat result.txt | cut -d ":" -f 6,7 | sort -n | cut -d " " -f 2 | sort -n)
down_cap=$( cat result.txt | cut -d : -f 6,7 | sort -n | cut -d " " -f 6| sort -n)
for value in "${down_cap[@]}";do
        if [ $value > 80000 ]; then
                cat result.txt | grep -B 1 "$value"
        fi
done

echo " All done, exiting"
```

when I execute the above script as ./script.sh, I get the error:
./script.sh: line 5: [: too many arguments
 All done, exiting

I have googled enough, and still not able to rectify this.

Comment: What is the format of the text in result.txt?

Comment: here is the sample data in result.txt:
/scratch/abcd/traces/shaper/parser/traces/194.105.3.30_1268072907_0.300000delta.txt Upstream: 92345 duration: 0 nlines 0 Downstream:14134 duration: 0 nlines 0...several sets like the above. I am trying to parse and extract upstream and downstream capacity , and grep those lines for which these values are > 80000

Comment: Comments are a poor medium for sharing formatted text files. Should probably put it on a pastebin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

```
if [ "$value" -gt 80000 ]; then
```

You use `-gt` for checking if A is bigger than B, not `>`. The quotation marks I merely added to prevent the script from failing in case $value is empty.

Comment: But now there is another problem. if ["$value" -gt 80000] returns true for all $value. Is there anything on the string vs numeric comparison?

Comment: @linuxAddict: `-gt` is numeric comparison; for string "greater than" makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare variable `$value` explicitly:

`declare -i value`

So, with the dominikh's and mine additions the code should look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
up_cap=$( cat result.txt | cut -d ":" -f 6,7 | sort -n | cut -d " " -f 2 | sort -n)
down_cap=$( cat result.txt | cut -d : -f 6,7 | sort -n | cut -d " " -f 6| sort -n)
for value in "${down_cap[@]}";do
  declare -i value
  if [ $value -gt 80000 ]; then
    cat result.txt | grep -B 1 "$value"
  fi
done

echo " All done, exiting"
```